# How to get the user id from Slack to bot service

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

I am creating a simple bot using Azure LUIS and this is my first one. I made some decent progress after doing some research and also now integrated with Slack as channel to test it.

The bot functionality is working fine, but I am looking to identify the user. So that I can personalize the bot conversation and also to pull the user specific information from his profile table.

Is there anyway, that I can get a UID or any reference ID of the slack user and so I can store that in my user table along with user profile?

So next time, when the user greets the bot, the bot can say "Hello, **John**." instead of justing say "Hello."

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by priting the whole session object, which is having all the required informaiton. This could be same as mentioned by Dana above, but after debugging, this follwing made simple without making any changes.

```
var slackID = session.message.address.user.id
```

With above, I am able to identify the user.

Thanks.

Comment: but how do you access the session variable?

Comment: Please see if this helps: 
https://github.com/bharathkarumudi/SUchatBot

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use the channelData object to get the `ApiToken`, and `user` values. For example, in C#, you could use `turnContext.Activity.ChannelData` to get those values in JSON:

```
{{
  "SlackMessage": {
    "token": "............",
    "team_id": "<TEAM ID>",
    "event": {
      "type": "message",
      "text": "thanks",
      "user": "<USER WHO MESSAGED>",
      "channel": "............",
      "channel_type": "channel"
    },
    "type": "event_callback",
    "event_id": ""............",
    "event_time": 1553119134,
    "authed_users": [
      "............",
      "<USER WHO MESSAGED>"
    ]
  },
  "ApiToken": "<ACTUAL TOKEN HERE>"
}}
```

Then, using those two pieces of information, you can then retrieve info from Slack.

```
https://slack.com/api/users.info?token=<ACTUAL TOKEN HERE>&user=<USER WHO MESSAGED>&pretty=1
```

And get a response that has the info you need:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "user": {
        "id": "<USER WHO MESSAGED>",
        "team_id": "<TEAM ID>",
        "real_name": "Dana V",
```

Ideally, you would would probably want to have bot user state setup and check that first, then if not there, then make the API call to Slack, then store in state. Therefore further requests don't need to go to Slack, but will just pull from the state store.

---

Basically, you could/should do this in the onTurn event. First, create your user state storage such as [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/ba4aeb136782154dffcab4ce6a0f795bdfcf295b/samples/javascript_nodejs/04.simple-prompt/index.js#L86).

Then you could  check for that value and write to it if not populated. [This example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/04.simple-prompt) on simple prompts, might be helpful. You won't need to prompt for your user's name, as this example does, but does read/write username from state. You could still use dialogs, but you won't need them for the name prompting as you are doing that dynamically.

You can see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/ba4aeb136782154dffcab4ce6a0f795bdfcf295b/samples/javascript_nodejs/04.simple-prompt/bot.js#L55) where username is being set and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/ba4aeb136782154dffcab4ce6a0f795bdfcf295b/samples/javascript_nodejs/04.simple-prompt/bot.js#L62) where it is being retrieved. In this case, it is in the dialogs, but again; you would/could just do in the turn context (using logic to get and if not there, set).

Comment: Thanks Dana. Is there any node.js reference for this implementation? Because I am writing my bot in node.js

Comment: Not too much different: `turnContext.activity.channelData`. The rest will be the same (JSON).

If my response resolved your question, please mark it as as an answer so that it may help others that have the same question.

Comment: If you dont mind, where exactly, I have to put this?  As I mentioned this is my first web app and my app.js file is here - https://github.com/bharathkarumudi/SUchatBot/blob/master/app.js