# Get the name of the sender of the message in slack using Microsoft Bot Framewok and C#

Tags: c#, botframework, slack, slack-api

I've set up a Microsoft Bot Framework Instance running in asp.net core. I've connected to Slack using Microsoft's Bot Channels Registration.

In my bot code, I have something like:

```cs
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(
            ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var message = $"From: {turnContext.Activity.From.Name})";
  await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(message, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

That always returns the "From: BotName". I expected that `From.Name` would be the name of the person sending the message that the bot is responding to.

Is there a way to get the sender's username? I can see the correct slack user id in `turnContext.Activity.ChannelData`, but I thought I'd be able to get at it through the normal bot framework API.

Comment: Do you want the userid or the displayname? ChannelData _is_ "normal" bot framework data.

For me `From.Name` returns the first part of my username. For example, my email is stuff@<domainname.com>, it returns 'stuff'. I think you can make additional calls into the slack API using info from ChannelData to get displayname, etc. I'll see if i can find something.

Answer (score 0):

The way `turnContext.Activity.From.Name` you used to get sender's name is right. I think this is the best way to get the sender's name.

According to `ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext` ,We can check the properties of this IMessageActivity object, and finally only `turnContext.Activity.From.Name` meets our requirements.

[image]

And u also want to get name from [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)  is available. From the pic below,u can see  members's info. From the api in official document, we can get the members of the specified activity by `GET /v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId}/members`.

[image]

Comment: So in my case, both the `From.Name` and `Recipient.Name` are the bot user when I use this in Slack.

Comment: @Haacked `From.Name` and `Recipient.Name` are the sender and receiver respectively. When the `Bot` is used in a production environment, it can be a non-bot user.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55232422/how-to-get-the-user-id-from-slack-to-bot-service/55271093#55271093). Essentially, one option is to use the slack API token that comes through with channeldata to make additional calls back into slack to retrieve what you need. OP also found that they could use the session object in node, but I am unable to accomplish that route.

Comment: "here" links to this post. I think you meant to link to another post. :)

Comment: Fixed the link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my code was correct, but I had Slack permissions incorrectly configured. It's been a while but I believe the necessary permissions were `users.profile:read` and `user:read` (maybe just one of these is required, but my bot uses both).

If you do not have these permissions granted to the bot in Slack, then Bot Framework appears to fail to get the sender's name and just uses the bot name for `turnContext.Activity.From.Name`.

This behavior is really confusing. I'd rather it be an empty string or say "(unknown)".